# How select results with a range of at most 300 points difference

Tags: sql

I have this registers:

```
ID, Points
----------
1, 100
2, 130
3, 400
4, 299
5, 50
6, 600
7, 800
```

How select **first 4** results with a range of at most 300 points difference? Example of results I expect:

```
ID, Points
----------
--------------->
5, 50 -----
1, 100 ----
2, 130 ----     first 4 ids with points range 300
4, 299 ----
--------------->
...
```

Other example:

```
ID, Points
----------
22, 700
20, 800
21, 850
23, 970
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not quite sure what's more important: the fact that you need 4 ids or that you need a range that it close to 300.
In your question you have the value 800 twice, with different ids.
However, ...)

Maybe you can use a combination of a analytic functions (window functions) and a self join for this.

TABLE (see also: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03bc40836ab7dbb16a3e78d56252815c))

```
ID  POINTS
1   100
2   130
3   400
4   299
5   50
6   600
7   800
22  700
20  800
21  850
23  970
```

Row numbers and ordering

```
select id, points
, row_number() over ( order by points ) rn_
from t ;

-- result
ID  POINTS  RN_
5   50      1
1   100     2
2   130     3
4   299     4
3   400     5
6   600     6
22  700     7
7   800     8
20  800     9
21  850     10
23  970     11
```

Use this query for a self join that satisfies the required conditions ..

```
select 
  t1.id, t1.points as from_
, t2.id, t2.points as to_
from (
  select id, points
  , row_number() over ( order by points ) rn_
  from t
) t1 join (
  select id, points
  , row_number() over ( order by points ) rn_
  from t
) t2 on t2.points <= t1.points + 300 and t2.rn_ - t1.rn_ = 3 ;

-- result
ID  FROM_   ID  TO_
5   50      4   299
1   100     3   400
6   600     20  800
22  700     21  850
7   800     23  970
```

If you only want to have the first row of this output, just add a "limit" (using Oracle eg fetch first row only -> see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03bc40836ab7dbb16a3e78d56252815c)).

**EDIT**

Considering your comments, it appears that you need 4 player IDs, which will be removed from the database (table) if they are playing, which depends on their scores being in the range (of 300 points).
In order to achieve this, maybe the following views will be helpful (Why views? Because they will make the DELETE statement easier to read.)

VIEW 1 - get the IDs of the 4 players with the lowest points

```
create or replace view fourplayers 
as
select id, points 
from (
  select id, points
  , row_number() over ( order by points ) rn_
  from t
)
where rn_ <= 4 ;

-- test
select * from fourplayers ;

-- result
ID  POINTS
5   50
1   100
2   130
4   299
```

VIEW 2 - should the 4 players play?

```
create or replace view rangeandplay
as
select 
  count(*) numberofplayers
, min( points ) minpoints
, max( points ) maxpoints
, max( points ) - min( points ) range
, case when max( points ) - min( points ) <= 300 then 'Y' else 'N' end play
from (
  select id, points from fourplayers
) ;

-- test
select * from rangeandplay ;

-- result
NUMBEROFPLAYERS MINPOINTS   MAXPOINTS   RANGE   PLAY
4               50          299         249     Y
```

DELETE the 4 players, if the PLAY flag is set to 'Y'

```
delete from t
where id in ( 
  select id from fourplayers 
) and (
  ( select play from rangeandplay ) = 'Y'
) ;

commit ;
```

If we now run  SELECT * FROM  rangeandplay, we see ...

```
select * from rangeandplay ;

-- result
NUMBEROFPLAYERS MINPOINTS   MAXPOINTS   RANGE   PLAY
4               400         800         400     N
```

-> The DELETE would not execute now, as PLAY is set to 'N'.
If another player eg with 450 points is INSERTed into the table,
DELETE would remove the first 4 players again.  See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3e72d23a136b62e92535e8666ca3394e).

Comment: Its a game matchmaker. So players with range 300 points will play together. So 4 players will battle but their points need to be max 300 points difference. PlayerID1 (50p), PlayerID80 (100p), PlayerID5 (299p), PlayerID800 (240p) will play toguether. So I will remove then from the database and search for other players. Points is from 0 to infinity so I need a query who works all possibility.

Comment: @GuilhermeIazzetta Thanks for that additional input!  So - what is supposed to happen if there are eg 20 players who all have the exact same amount of points (each)?

Comment: In this case I will take the first 4 players (randomly), delete them from the bank and send them to a match. There can be 5 matches with players with the same number of points, no problem. What cannot happen is that the first 4 records of my query exist players with scores with a range greater than 300.

Comment: @GuilhermeIazzetta Some changes made to the first queries, but the views (added in the EDIT section) will probably be more useful for you.